# Question about understanding of Pytorch .named_modules() loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, resnet

I am referring to this implementation here:

https://github.com/hszhao/semseg/blob/master/model/pspnet.py

In line 49-58, the author writes:

```
for n, m in self.layer3.named_modules():
    if 'conv2' in n:
        m.dilation, m.padding, m.stride = (2, 2), (2, 2), (1, 1)
    elif 'downsample.0' in n:
        m.stride = (1, 1)

for n, m in self.layer4.named_modules():
    if 'conv2' in n:
        m.dilation, m.padding, m.stride = (4, 4), (4, 4), (1, 1)
    elif 'downsample.0' in n:
        m.stride = (1, 1)
```

What exactly is happening in these loops?

My understanding is, that the author is creatig a resnet model (his resnet.py here https://github.com/hszhao/semseg/blob/master/model/resnet.py ) and then is calling the different layers, which he implemented in his resnet class to forward them below.

layer3 and layer4 in resnet.py are made by calling the function `def _make_layer(self, block, planes, blocks, stride=1):` , so I assume that when `.named_modules()` is used in the loops, it is looping through the modules in this `def _make_layer` function, is it? If so, what happens in the elif part? There is no module, that is called `downsample.0` ? (The only modules are nn.Conv2d and nn.BatchNorm2d )

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of resnet that used there.

```
model = ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 4, 6, 3], **kwargs)
```

In Resnet class, it calls super because of this, it has **self.downsample** If it's not none:

```
if self.downsample is not None:
        residual = self.downsample(x)
```

it could have Sequential or another layer.

```
class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    expansion = 4

    def __init__(self, inplanes, planes, stride=1, downsample=None):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(inplanes, planes, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(planes, planes, kernel_size=3, stride=stride,
                               padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(planes, planes * self.expansion, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes * self.expansion)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.downsample = downsample
        self.stride = stride
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the loop itself? Or maybe I am missing your point, but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: named_modules returns all modules in the network, yielding both the name of the module as well as the module itself according to https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.named_modules. So "conv2" and "batchform" is there like you said but downsample could be defined even it didn't there. It comes from super class.

Comment: Ok, I see. But then I do not understand, what downsample exactly does. Why does it take "stride" as an parameter? In the entire network, all that seems to happen with an input is `residual = self.downsample(x)`. What does it do?

Comment: I don't exactly see the authors' point but probably the goal is settings stride as 1 when value is something else. That **m.stride = (1, 1)** sets potential module's stride. You may search for other resnet implementations.

Comment: If the intent was to set stride to 1, isn´t that already done in the if part? I have seen other implementations, but they do not really help me to understand exactly this part.

Comment: stride is set only when conv2 and downsample.0. If it's batchnorm it doesn't set it.